# Is it correct to end the sentence with "between"?

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction, grammaticality, sentence-structure

This is what I wrote

> Where c1, and c2 are the terms the system is trying to find the similarity between.

is using 'between' at the end correct?

Comment: You've asked 125 questions here. Please at least get in the habit of using an upper-case I, and put no space before a question mark.

Comment: This is _not_ a sentence. And further to the point by @J.R. - in English we capitalize the initial word in a sentence. Anyway: _Where c1 and c2 are the terms between which the system is trying to find the similarity._ However, the phrase as written is understandable—awkward, but understandable.

Comment: @J.R. there is a quote in Italy: "one coffee = 3 euros, please one coffee = 2 euros, google morning please one coffee = 1 euro"

Comment: @MarcoD: Well, if you want to make this a matter of manners and politeness, I think it's rather inconsiderate to keep writing [questions](http://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/54966/revisions) in [such a way](http://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/32357/revisions) that [people](http://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/55122/revisions) are [needing](http://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/99896/revisions) to [clean](http://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/89164/revisions) them [up](http://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/73263/revisions) for [you](http://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/61652/revisions).

Comment: @J.R. I may have done a mistake. However, you would need to pay 20 euros for a coffee in Italy. Cheers

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Such politeness by using "please" in a question doesn't work in SE sites and it is even impolite! Because people here are not supposed to reply personal requests, but they are here to answer questions which benefits many people! then don't make your question looks like a personal request by using "please" and direct sentences, but make them a useful question for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

I would be inclined to go the more direct route:

> ... where c1 and c2 are the terms whose similarity the system is trying to find.

This structure keeps the emphasis on the terms and eliminates the dangling preposition.

Per @ColleenV, please note that while "whose" is typically used to refer to an animate object, English does not have an inanimate pronoun to handle this situation, so "whose" is correct.

Comment: When did 'between' change from a preposition to a participle? You may want to mention that some folks have problems with using 'whose' to refer to inanimate things (even though it's the only word we have in English that will work until we steal a new one from some poor unsuspecting language). [Grammar Girl](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/whose-for-inanimate-objects) has an article on this. It's not wrong, but sometimes it's a good idea to avoid things that people incorrectly perceive as wrong just to avoid distracting your reader.

Comment: Problem between keyboard and chair as far as participles go - edited. I hadn't thought about that on the pronoun choice - but I'm not sure I want to change my answer either, as I think it is noticeably stronger phrasing. But definitely something to keep in mind.

Comment: Oh I didn't mean you should change it - I was just thinking it would be a footnote sort of thing. Learners have a lot of folks telling them "rules" and I think it helps to explain that sometimes those rules aren't exactly correct.

Comment: I realized that was what you meant after I commented - and added a note to the answer. All good!

Answer (score 0):

> ... where c1, and c2 are the terms the system is trying to find the similarity between.

I am guessing that this clause is used following an equation or a clause containing c1 and c2. [If this is so, please edit your question to make this clear]. I have indicated that the equation or clause is missing in the usual way, using three dots: this is called an [ellipsis](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/ellipses.html) symbol.

In your clause, [between](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/between) is a preposition. If you end a sentence with a preposition, it's called a [dangling preposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preposition_stranding). Some people don't like dangling prepositions and write very complicated sentences to avoid them. But if the sentence is more understandable that way, let that preposition dangle.

In this case, there is a very simple way of avoiding the dangling preposition. Just re-arrange the clause like this:

> ... where the system is trying to find the similarity between [the terms] c1 and c2.

Comment: But I think the second sentence looses the emphasis on the terms...

Answer (score -2):

Just add a word for making it an understandable (math) sentence.

> Where c1, and c2 are the terms, the system is trying to find the similarity between **them** (both).

Comment: The sentence has two main verbs **are** and **is**: you need to divide it into two clauses. The original version works because there is an implied relative pronoun **that**  to make the second part a separate clause, "Where c1 and c2 are the terms [that] the system is trying to find the similarity between", Your added **them** replaces the implied relative pronoun, so the clauses are no longer separate. You need to separate the clauses with **and**... "Where c1 and c2 are the terms, and the system is trying to find the similarity between them"... or insert a full stop...

Comment: Welcome to ELL. Please review our [**tour**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and [**Help Center**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) pages. They will help you write useful answers. We also hope you will improve your English by asking questions of your own!